# Docker secure connection with ssh port forwarding

Tags: ssl, docker, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, ssh-tunnel

I made a ssh tunnel for port forwarding to get mapped a port on my laptop with port on the remote host (`your-mv.com`):

```
ssh -nfNT -L 3376:your-mv.com:3376 login@server.com
```

Then I changed `docker_host` and setup docker `tls` variables:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=localhost:3376
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/my/path
```

And I run:

```
docker ps
```

But I have an error:

```
Get https://localhost:3376/v1.26/containers/json: x509: certificate is valid for your-mv.com, not localhost
```

Could you help me what did I wrong and how to overcome this problem?

**UPD**

Common name of my laptop is `subject= /CN=kenenbek`. Common name of `CA` is `subject= /CN=cert-authority.com` and common name of remote host is `subject= /CN=your-vm.com`.

Answer (score 1):

**DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY** is set and the certificate has the Common Name of ***your-mv.com***, but **DOCKER_HOST** was set to localhost.

Do not set **DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY**.

Comment: but I must use tls connection.

Comment: `subject= /CN=kenenbek` is user on my laptop

Comment: DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY checks the server certificate.  If the CN doesn't match, you get the error.

Comment: in `docker-cert` folder I have a `CA`'s certificate and laptop's certificate with key. `CA`'s common name is `CN=cert-authority.com`

Comment: Docker is detecting a certificate that is valid only for your-mv.com.  The CN of the server certificate must match DOCKER_HOST.

On the other hand, do you really need TLS with a SSH tunnel?

Comment: I need a ssh-port forwarding because I don't have a direct access to remote machine. 
Yes, CN of remote machine is `your-vm.com` but `DOCKER_HOST` variable on my laptop is `localhost:3376`. How to make it appropriate?

Comment: Unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY on the client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136286/discussion-between-roma-karageorgievich-and-ricardo-branco).